# Showing Error Class 'Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Mysql4_Setup' not found in magento?

Tags: magento

I am unable to open my site showing error

```
Class 'Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Mysql4_Setup' not found in /home1/griar/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php on line 234
```

I am unable to find the fault
if anyone knows this, please help me out.
Thanks!
In admin, also showing the same error

```
Class 'Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Mysql4_Setup' not found in /home1/griar/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php on line 234
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using an extension from Aitoc.
Either disable the extension if you don't need it, or contact them for support.

If you just installed the extension, clear the cache and disable the compilation.

Comment: But admin page is also not opening showing the same error. then how i will clear the cache and disable the compilation

Comment: You can clear the cache by removing all contents from folder `var/cache` and you can disable compilation by editing the file `includes/config.php` and commenting the code lines in there. There should be 2 of them.